# Read the string value of a UITableView Section Title

Tags: xcode, uitableview, sectionheader

I want to push the section title of a UITableView to another view controller's section title.
But I can't figure out a way to read an existing section title. The existing section title is dynamically constructed and I'd rather reuse it than reconstructing it again.

```
 if (indexPath.section == 0) {

      SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
      secondViewController.strValueHolder = FOO_section.sectionTitle; // FOO Code
      [[self navigationController] pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
      [secondViewController release];

 }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call the titleForHeaderInSection method directly:

```
NSString *sectionTitle = 
    [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
```

or move the code you currently have in titleForHeaderInSection to a custom method and call that custom method from titleForHeaderInSection and the place where you are pushing another view controller.

Comment: Yes thanks for your response. I opted for the second option, using a custom method and calling it from multiple places.